# Как хранить и изменять переменные в энергонезависимой памяти ESP32

Tags: поиск, arduino, esp32, flash-память, arduino-ide

Есть устройство на базе `ESP32`, в устройстве стоит SD-карта с файлом, на котором отсортированный список идентификационных номеров (`hex` формат), по которым осуществляется поиск и предоставляется определенный доступ. Список периодически обновляется с удаленного сервера. Из-за большого числа этих номеров (`~500000`) поиск осуществляется посредством массива индексов (для значения массива берутся 4 старших разряда каждого 32 номера). Сейчас предварительно сгенерированный массив просто забит в код программы, как глобальная переменная, это работает и поиск по файлу на SD карте занимает порядка 60 ms, но это лишает возможности изменять этот массив в соответствии с измененным списком номеров, точнее, изменять его так, чтобы после перезагрузки устройства он остался в последнем состоянии, а не в том, которое забито в коде. Была попытка использовать эмуляцию `EEPROM` (NVS-раздел flash памяти), но имеющееся API предоставляет возможность лишь поиска по конкретному ключу, а это, увы, не подходит. Хотелось бы просто иметь возможность держать этот массив в энергонезависимом куске памяти и обращаться к нему из программы, как если бы он был простой переменной. Для ясности приведу кусок кода, как сейчас происходит поиск:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 15625; i++) {
    if (searchIndexHex <= index_mass[i]) {
      if (i != 0) {
        file.seek((i - 1) * 18 * 32);
      } else file.seek(0);
      break;
    }
  }
```

То есть, после считывания, условно, метки с пропуска, берем 4 старших разряда от её номера и бежим искать подобное по массиву `index_mass`, когда находим – соответственно смещаем указатель в файле на SD-карте и дальше осуществляем поиск по файлу. Как лаконично осуществить подобное с помощью NVS не очень представляю, может есть способ расположить этот массив в энергонезависимой части памяти, при этом сохранив к нему доступ в том виде, в каком он сейчас? Или какие-то удобные альтернативы?

Разработка ведется в `Arduino IDE`, соответственно, с использованием Arduino-библиотек

Comment: ¿Поиск простым перебором что ли? ¿Почему бы не присылать индекс с сервера вместе с файлом?

Comment: @user7860670, сервер не всегда может быть доступен, потому устройство должно иметь при себе и массив индексов и файл с идентификаторами. А так, поиск по массиву индексов да, просто перебором, по файлу же в зависимости от найденного индекса, переходим в точку, которая соответствует полученному индексу и сканируем следующие 32 идентификатора, не весь файл до конца, конечно же. Возможно топорно, но работает и устраивает полностью, в плане скорости поиска, по крайней мере

Comment: ¿Так я не понял, а что мешает присылать массив вместе с новыми данными с сервера, вместо захардкоживания в коде?

Comment: @user7860670 хранить его как? В какой части памяти его держать? Пришла обнова, всё ок, затем сервер стал недоступен и произошла перезагрузка в связи с отключением питания. К серверу доступа нет, откуда взять массив? Где его вообще нужно держать?

Comment: У вас же написано - в устройстве стоит SD-карта с файлом, на котором отсортированный список идентификационных номеров - держите там же и файл с индексом, обновляя его вместе со списком

Comment: @user7860670 так массив индексов для того был сделан, что читать с sd – долго, потому индексы и лежат в памяти ESP. Да, прочитать файлик поменьше и из него прыгнуть на нужный адрес файлика побольше будет быстрее, чем сходу пытаться построчно читать большой файл. Но, все же, вопрос в том, что хотелось бы иметь индексы в энергонезависимом участке, при этом читая их, как сейчас, то есть, будто захардкоженные. Есть ли вообще такая возможность, вот в чем вопрос